# sum using loops

Tags: r

I want to sum (1/3)+(3/5)+ ⋯ +(99/101) using loops in R
I have tried this and I want to check if its right and is there other solutions also if we can do it with for loops and repeat loops.

```
sum <- 0
i <- 1
j <- 3
while (i<=99 && j<=101 ) {
  sum <- sum+i/j
  i <- i+2
  j <- j+2
}
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Although you can also do

```
sum <- 0
i <- 1
while (i<=99) {
  sum <- sum+i/(i+2)
  i <- i+2
}
sum
```

```
sum <- 0
for (i in seq(1,99,2)) {
  sum <- sum+i/(i+2)
}
sum
```

```
sum <- 0
i <- 1
repeat {
  sum <- sum+i/(i+2)
  if (i == 99) break
  i <- i + 2
}
sum
```

```
i <- seq(1,99,2)
sum(i / (i + 2))
```

Ah, you'd better use another name than `sum` for your variable.

Comment: why? Do you mean because sum already is a function in R?

Comment: Note whatif's last example. It is important. R is designed such that its objects generally carry all the information internally you need to iterate through the list. This completely wipes out 2 classes of errors that are very common when making loops: Starting at the wrong index and counting the number of loops needed incorrectly. This is where the adage to generally avoid for loops in R comes from.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the idea of odd numbers formula where `2*n - 1` and `2*n + 1` are two consecutive odd numbers

```
result <- 0
for(i in 1:50){
    result <- result + (2*i - 1)/(2*i + 1)
}
```

- output

```
result

#>[1] 46.10465
```